# Validation of drop down having dynamic multiple drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question is to :
Two drop downs should not be able to select same option.

Dynamically multiple drop downs are created. Since its dynamically id can't be used to with my jquery validation. 
So, I tried doing my validation using class. 
But I can not able to write correct validation jquery code for it. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript set.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

run snippet below pick the same value in both drop downs and hit submit you will receive validation error

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var arr = [{
    val: 1,
    text: 'One'
  }, {
    val: 2,
    text: 'Two'
  }, {
    val: 3,
    text: 'Three'
  }, {
    val: 4,
    text: 'Four'
  }, {
    val: 5,
    text: 'Five'
  }, {
    val: 6,
    text: 'Six'
  }];

  var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#container');
  var sel2 = $('<select>').appendTo('#container');
  $(arr).each(function() {
    sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
    sel2.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
  });

  $('select').change(function(event) {
    var myArray = [];
    $("select").each(function() {
      myArray.push($(this).val())
    })
    if (myArray.length != new Set(myArray).size) {
      alert('validation failed');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: It should be done on change of the dropdown. Extra button should not be used.

Comment: So just change submit.click to select.change

Comment: Thanks It really works.
But I my case, options are generated from DB.

Comment: again I fail to see the problem, of course it is generated from a DB why else would you make it dynamic.  It is still generated dynamically so what's the difference?